# sap.m.UploadCollection, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i try to implement the UploadCollection, according to this [example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UploadCollection/preview). But i can`t make it runnable.

DataMock:

```js
var data = {
"attachments" : [
{
"contributor" : "Susan Baker",
"documentId" : "64469d2f-b3c4-a517-20d6-f91ebf85b9da",
"enableEdit" : true,
"enableDelete" : true,
"fileName" : "Screenshot.jpg",
"fileSize" : 20,
"mimeType" : "image/jpg",
"thumbnailUrl" : "",
"uploadedDate" : "2014-07-30",
"url" : "image/orianda.png"
}, {
"contributor" : "John Smith",
"documentId" : "5082cc4d-da9f-2835-2c0a-8100ed47bcde",
"enableEdit" : true,
"enableDelete" : false,
"fileName" : "Notes.txt",
"fileSize" : 10,
"mimeType" : "text/plain",
"thumbnailUrl" : "",
"uploadedDate" : "2014-08-01",
"url" : "image/orianda.png"
}
]};
```

**Dosen`t work**

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(), "runtime" )
var oRuntime = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("runtime");
Runtime.setData( data );
```

*and view.xml:*

```xml
    <UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="55" multiple="true" change="onChange" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" fileRenamed="onFileRenamed" fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch" uploadComplete="onUploadComplete" items="{runtime>/attachments}">
        <items>
            <UploadCollectionItem contributor="{contributor}" documentId="{documentId}" fileName="{fileName}" fileSize="{fileSize}" mimeType="{mimeType}" thumbnailUrl="{thumbnailUrl}" uploadedDate="{uploadedDate}" url="{url}" enableEdit="{enableEdit}" enableDelete="{enableDelete}" /> 
       </items>
            </UploadCollection>
```

**Works almost:**

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel() )
var oRuntime = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
Runtime.setData( data );
```

*and view.xml:*

```xml
    <UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="55" multiple="true" change="onChange" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" fileRenamed="onFileRenamed" fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch" uploadComplete="onUploadComplete" items="{/attachments}">
        <items>
            <UploadCollectionItem contributor="{contributor}" documentId="{documentId}" fileName="{fileName}" fileSize="{fileSize}" mimeType="{mimeType}" thumbnailUrl="{thumbnailUrl}" uploadedDate="{uploadedDate}" url="{url}" enableEdit="{enableEdit}" enableDelete="{enableDelete}" /> 
       </items>
            </UploadCollection>
```

The first version loads the two items, but the values for each item is empty.

The second version loads the items correct. The only difference is the **named model**.

**Both versions** throw an error, when i try to upload something.

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined -

What did i wrong?

---

**update**: i figured out; its caused by the mock server.The rootURI dosent macht with the upload URI, therefore it should not influents it.
I will open a bug report, if someone can confirm me that this is a bug.

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.MockServer");
var sMockdataBaseUrl = "testdata/data/"
var sMetadataUrl = "testdata/metadata.xml"
sap.ui.core.util.MockServer.config({  
            autoRespond : true,
          autoRespondAfter : 3000
          });
var oMockServer = new sap.ui.core.util.MockServer({
            rootUri : '/server/'
        });

        oMockServer.simulate(sMetadataUrl, {
            'sMockdataBaseUrl' : sMockdataBaseUrl,
            'bGenerateMissingMockData' : true
        });

        oMockServer.start();
```

Comment: if you set a named model you need to set the binding-path as `contributor="{runtime>contributor}"`

Comment: And I think your UploadCollection is missing an uploadUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated the scenario and it is perfectly working fine.

Here is example I tried.

https://github.com/Sarathchandrach/openui5examples/tree/master/UploadCollectionDemo.

and Sample code I tried.

Controller:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); 
oModel.setData({
    modelData: data
});
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "oAppView");
```

View:

```xml
<UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="55" multiple="true" change="onChange" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" fileRenamed="onFileRenamed" fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch" uploadComplete="onUploadComplete" items="{oAppView>/modelData/attachments}">
    <items>
        <UploadCollectionItem contributor="{oAppView>contributor}" documentId="{oAppView>documentId}" fileName="{oAppView>fileName}" fileSize="{oAppView>fileSize}" mimeType="{oAppView>mimeType}" thumbnailUrl="{oAppView>thumbnailUrl}" uploadedDate="{oAppView>uploadedDate}" url="{oAppView>url}" enableEdit="{oAppView>enableEdit}" enableDelete="{oAppView>enableDelete}" /> 
   </items>
</UploadCollection>
```